# Arrow anti pattern with crutch

Tags: c#

How can I improve this code and avoid crutch? Can I use a case operator?

```
public bool Crutch;

public void Resize(SizeChangedEventArgs input)
    {
        if (input.NewSize.Width < 450 && Crutch)
        {
            if (!ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MultiViewModel>().EightBoxesCommandIsEnabled)
            {
                ChangeToSmall(2, 2);
            }
        }

        if (input.NewSize.Width < 550 && !Crutch)
        {
            if (!ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MultiViewModel>().EightBoxesCommandIsEnabled)
            {
                ChangeToSmall(3, 2);
            }
            Crutch = true;
        }

        if (input.NewSize.Width > 450 && Crutch)
        {
            if (!ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MultiViewModel>().EightBoxesCommandIsEnabled)
            {
                ChangeToBig(3, 2);
            }
            Crutch = false;
        }

        if (input.NewSize.Width > 550 && !Crutch)
        {
            if (!ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MultiViewModel>().EightBoxesCommandIsEnabled)
            {
                ChangeToBig(4, 2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is lacking context. Show us also the code for `ChangeToSmall` and `ChangeToBig`, why do you need `Crutch` (and is it also accessed elsewhere),  etc. There is some odd logic in this method, we'd really benefit from an explanation of what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Context is important. What is your code supposed to do and how will it be used?

Answer (score 3):

If `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MultiViewModel>().EightBoxesCommandIsEnabled` evaluates to true you never do anything; so hoist it out of the if statements and do an early return:

```
public void Resize(SizeChangedEventArgs input)

    if(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MultiViewModel>().EightBoxesCommandIsEnabled) 
        return;

    if (input.NewSize.Width < 450 && Crutch)
    {
        ChangeToSmall(2, 2);
    }
    //...
}
```

You can name crutch into something better that describes what it represents. Or keep whether ChangeToSmall or ChangeToBig was called last and replace crutch with that property.

```
void ChangeToBig(int, int){
    lastChangeCalledBig = true;

    //...
}

void ChangeToSmall(int, int){
    lastChangeCalledBig = false;

    //...
}
```